# Conditional Join tables structure

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

i have three tables like these:

1. `PARTY_ANIMALS` [ID, ...] *--> contains all the animals participating in the party*
2. `DOGS` [ID, id_dog, name_dog] *--> contains a list of dogs with respective name*
3. `CATS` [ID, id_cat, name_cat] *--> contains a list of cats with respective name*

I would execute a query that fetch PART_ANIMALS and join DOGS or CAT based on some values in

PARTY_ANIMALS (then performing a conditional join) and give me back a result table made in this way:

RESULT_TABLE [animal_type, id(id_dog or id_cat), name(name_dog or name_cat)].

What is the right way do this? What values in PARTY_ANIMALS table i need for correctly join with the others tables? and what kind of query i need to obtain my result table?

Comment: why dont you select cats and dogs separately and then merge results?

Comment: you mean if i create the tables party_dogs and a party_cats? then how i can merge it and obtain the value animal_type in the result table?

Comment: on mysql side do: SELECT ... PARTY_ANIMALS JOIN DOGS and second query SELECT ... PARTY_ANIMALS JOIN CATS  and then merge resulting arrays in php or whichever language you use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using `left join` and `coalesce()`:

```
select (case when id_cat is not null then 'Cat' else 'Dog' end) as animal_type,
       coalesce(c.id_cat, d.id_dog) as id,
       coalesce(c.name_cat, d.name_dog) as name
from party_animals pa left join
     cats c
     on pa.id = c.id_cat left join
     dogs d
     on pa.id = d.id_dog;
```

This will allow the SQL engine to use indexes for the `join`s.

Also, you need to be quite careful that the id columns in `cats` and `dogs` have distinct values.  Or, at least until scientists can come up with a way to create a hybrid cat-dog.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT d_c.animal_type,
       d_c.id,
       d_c.name
FROM party_animals a
INNER JOIN (SELECT 'dog' animal_type,
                   id id_a,
                   id_dog id,
                   name_dog name
            FROM dogs 
            UNION ALL 
            SELECT 'cat' animal_type,
                   id id_a,
                   id_cat id,
                   name_cat name
            FROM cats 
            ) d_c ON a.id = d_c.id_a
```

Comment: this looks like can be a solution... but in this case what happens if i have the same in both in dog table and cat table?

Comment: the join will be correct because it's using the id (renamed id_a), in your final table you will see a dog and a cat with the same id (coming from colums id_dog or id_cat). Of course in this case the final id is not unique, but the couple animal_type-id is

Comment: yes but how can i get the correct row? i need an additive value in party_animal... is a good practice add type_animal field in party_animal table and do some like this:

Comment: what is the correct row? which result are you expecting? the good practice depends on what you need. For me it's better to avoid tables like dogs and cats and keep everything in a single table with an unique ID and an animal type column

Comment: actually every row in party_animal is connected only to a row in dog OR a row in cat, results from not corresponding table are inexact... i can define in which table there is the correspondeing row adding a field animal_type in party animal and adding this to your query...                                             ...FROM cats ) d_c ON a.id = d_c.id_a AND a.animal_type = d_c.animal_type

Comment: you don't need that additional join condition, I added the animal_type column, with a hardcoded value, because I saw that in your tables you have two IDs (ID and ID_dogs/cats) and in the results you wanted to show ID_dogs/cats and not the ID, which is the column that links party_animals to dogs and cats.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63765/discussion-between-domenico-and-mucio).